# How to modify the HTML of a text node (type 3) / how to wrap it in an HTML span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

On finding a text node (nodeType = 3), how to tinker with its HTML?

In the sense, suppose the text node's value (data or textContent) is `This is textual content`, how to surround this with HTML - say a bold tag...make it **`This is textual content`**.

Changing the `textContent` writes out the HTML tags as well - `<b>This is textual content</b>`

How to make it render as **`This is textual content`**.

Javascript / Jquery

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your question seems fairly raw DOM, but you've mentioned jQuery.

#### Raw DOM stuff:

You can create the `b` element, insert it before the text node, and then move the text node into it ([live example](http://jsbin.com/ibevoh/3)):

```
function wrapNode(textNode, tagName) {
    var wrapper = document.createElement(tagName);
    textNode.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper, textNode);
    wrapper.appendChild(textNode);
    return wrapper;
}
```

Another way is to manipulate the `innerHTML` property of the text node's parent `Element`, but if you do that note that any descendant elements you update in that way are *replaced* (so the new ones won't have the event handlers and such attached to the old ones).

Further reading:

- [DOM2 Core spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/) - very widely supported
- [DOM2 HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/) - very widely supported
- [DOM3 Core spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/) - mostly supported, but you need to feature-detect some things
- [HTML5 DOM interfaces](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-dom-interfaces.html#common-dom-interfaces) - support varies

#### jQuery:

jQuery mostly doesn't give you the raw text nodes, it's more `Element`-focussed. But you might look at its [`wrap`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/), [`wrapAll`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/), and [`wrapInner`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/) functions. `wrapInner` is probably closest to what you want ([live example](http://jsbin.com/ibevoh/4)):

```
$(parent_element_selector).click(function() {
  $(this).wrapInner("<b>").unbind("click");
});
```

Comment: Thanks TJ! Much appreciate the detailed explanation.

Comment: Your function cannot be called within a loop! Had me off the walls. I extended my fine-tune into an answer, check it out

Answer (score 2):

Use `$(selector).html('<strong>Something here</strong>');`

or

create a class in CSS and then use `addClass();` to the parent of the text

Answer (score 2):

With jQuery you can use `.wrapInner()` to add a tag around some text. For example, with the following HTML

```
<span>Text goes here</span>
```

You can use the following jQuery code to add `<b>` tags

```
$('span').wrapInner('<b>');
```

This results in the following HTML:

```
<span><b>Text goes here</b></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also try it this way:

HTML

```
<div id="test">
    This is textual content
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$('#test').wrapInner('<strong>');
```

That will surround everything inside `#test` with a `strong` tag.

Answer (score 1):

To extend T.J's answer to better fit the OP's requirement, the provided function cannot be called within a loop (looping through nodes).

Personally, I had to convert all direct text nodes into spans, much like the OP hinted at (by referencing `nodeType==3`).

**The problem** is that when converting the nodes inside a loop, **it throws off the index!** Here's some fine-tuned code that converts all text nodes into wrapped nodes (optimized):

```
for(var txtnodes=[],nodes=XXXX.childNodes,i=0,j=nodes.length;i<j;i++) {
 if(nodes[i].nodeType==3) txtnodes[txtnodes.length] = nodes[i];
}
for(var m=0,n=txtnodes.length;m<n;m++) {
 var span = document.createElement('span');
 pg.insertBefore(span,txtnodes[m]);
 span.appendChild(txtnodes[m]);
}
```

This function effectively "saves them for later" and converts them after the fact. The variable declarations are all compacted and inline, and all the loops are optimized for long node trees.

There aren't any other articles on Google about this topic, so happy coding to any future adventurers.